# Is this a non-finite verb phrase?

Tags: verbs, nonfinite-verbs

"You **watch** it *struggling to escape* and eventually *getting squashed* with a shoe.

Is "getting squashed" a non-finite verb phrase?

I believe "watch" is the main verb, and then "struggling" and "to escape" are non-finite verbs. And then "getting" is non-finite, but I hesitated on whether "squashed" is finite or non-finite. I think "getting squashed" is a non-finite phrase? Because you could change the sentence to: "You **watched** it *struggling to escape* and eventually *getting squashed*..."

Is this correct?

Comment: More than that. It comes from a much longer conjoined sentence with all the non-finite verb phrases safely after auxiliaries or governing verbs; much has been deleted by rule: _You watch it struggling to escape and [you watch it] eventually getting squashed with a shoe_. All of those non-finite VPs (_struggling (to escape), getting (squashed with a shoe)_) are complement (object) NPs, which can be either infinitives or participles (often called "gerunds" if they're present participles). _Watch_, being a sense verb, can take gerunds, and _struggle_ takes an infinitive. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is the so-called *get*-passive; here "getting squashed" is a less formal variant of "being squashed." In traditional grammar, "being squashed" is a *passive gerund*; in Lawler's terminology it will be something much more complicated, but in any case "squashed" is not a finite verb.